File `commons/colors.tex' not found
I have tex script that used to work fine. After updating the libraries, I am getting the following error message:
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5-generic-helper.
sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5-mapping.def
)))

! LaTeX Error: File `commons/colors.tex' not found.

Can you please help me?

The log fragment you show implies /texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty has \input{commons/colors} but my copy does not. Is that the full log or did you omit some ) somewhere? (you have 5 ( and four )  implying the input is in the first file shown.)

@David the latest version has the input: https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/blob/63945865c239c6f9c14ac7d66339920d1bcf64c7/moderncviconsawesome.sty#L25 (also on CTAN)

@Marijn ah I guess I will get it later then (unless Karl has banned that file from texlive, such a generic name is really bad) Sami you can for now copy https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moderncv/moderncv/63945865c239c6f9c14ac7d66339920d1bcf64c7/commons/colors.tex  to your local machine

@DavidCarlisle but \input{commons/colors} can't never work unless every user creates a local colors.tex, can't it?

@DavidCarlisle oh no, it actually works. kpathsea finds thats.

@UlrikeFischer yes that works but the problem is \input{colors}  also works so it grabs that generic name from all documents for everyone whether or not this class is used. I left a comment at github https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/issues/136#issuecomment-2222731332

@DavidCarlisle yes the name is bad (and Karl will never let it pass).

@DavidCarlisle I could copy it file you provided to my local machine. But please excuse my ignorance, and provide me with the location :)... would that be in c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/?

I tried in tex/latex/ and in tex/latex/moderncv/ both did not work...

the link I gave has the file, just copy it from there

place it on commons/color.tex subdirectory of the  folder with your document. placing it in a  commons subdirectory of tex/latex/moderncv would also work but in that case you woul dneed to run maketexlsr to re-create the file search hash.

Happens here, too. docker run -it --rm -v "c:\temp\mappe":/workdir registry.gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive:latest bash. I am trying to find an image, where it worked.

Please update your package. PR https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/pull/195 fixed the issue. Package available via https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv.
tlmgr update moderncv


I just did, the error is gone, but my custom styles have been thrown out. I guess there are changes to take into concideration. Everything is black now :D

Report to https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/issues - think, this is a bug which should be fixed.

Thank you @koppor: here's the link: https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/issues/198
